# Issue reconnecting to periphal device with iPhone (QT)

Tags: ios, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a qt app running on Android and iOS. The Bluetooth part of the code is in c++ and currently works for Android.

Currently on the iOS side I can discover the device and pair to it and connect. However when I go to connect to the device again after closing and reopening app (or restarting the phone) I cannot reconnect to the device.

I save the Devicee UUID that iOS creates for the device (since there is no MAC Address) and I get the error from my QLowEnergyController that says "Remote Device Not Found".

Things I have tried after pairing:
1. Restart app and try connecting.
2. Go into settings and manually connect to the device. Still doesn't find the device.

Are there any specific steps to reconnect to iOS?

I am expecting that the app will connect my iPhone to the device just like in Android.